# How do I join a vector of vectors using a separator in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust, concatenation, separator

If I have a vector of strings, I can join them to a single string using a separator:

```
assert_eq!("a b c", vec!["a", "b", "c"].join(" "));
```

I'm looking for the equivalent for a vector of vectors. For example:

```
let vec_of_vecs = vec![vec![1], vec![2, 3]];
assert_eq!(vec![1, 0, 2, 3], vec_of_vecs.join(0)); // this doesn't work
```

Using `flatten` does not work for me since I need the original vectors to be separated by a certain element in the joined vector. I've tried something like `.flat_map(|v| v.iter().chain(iter::once(0)) )` to add the separator before flattening but I didn't get it to work. (Also, this would add a redundant separator at the end.)

So is there a feature like `join` but for vectors? And if not, what would be the most idiomatic way to join a vector of vectors with a separator?

Comment: tl;dr `vec_of_vecs.into_iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<_>>()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this doesn't solve my problem. I've edited the question to explain why flatten doesn't work for me, emphasising the separator aspect.

Comment: Look into the implementation of [`intersperse`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.intersperse) in the `itertools` crate (or literally use `intersperse` from itertools). [Link to `itersperse.rs`](https://github.com/rust-itertools/itertools/blob/master/src/intersperse.rs).

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for! If the question gets reopened I'll write an answer with the example fixed.